# Running a script/query on all documents in a couchdb database/view

Tags: javascript, couchdb, batch-processing

I recently discovered CouchDB and it fits perfectly for what I am working at today. Working with the Futon interface, and calling the http API works fin, but something is missing.

During the design of my application, I sometimes want to apply some changes on all the documents in the database. As a simplified example, lets say all my documents have a field named "type", and I decided to pick strings as type instead of numbers.

Now I have to go over all my documents in Futon, and change the string into a number, which is a silly job.

Another example would be deleting all documents that apply to a certain condition.

The perfect solution would be some kind of engine which can call a javascript function per document, and I can return the new value for the document.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is already there: [the API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API). Note that Futon also only a wrapper around the API.

Not sure what middleware you use (node?, php?) but if you're familiar with the API it should be easy to:

1. Get all documents
2. Change field "type" (string instead of number)
3. Save the docs (use [_bulk_docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API))

Comment: I sure know how to use the API, but what I want to do now is just a 'quick' operation. I do not want to write any supplemetary (retrieve the docs, save the docs, ...) code just to do a bulk operation.

Comment: No, there is no tool like that in couch.

Comment: I will know what tool I will be writing in the near future then ;) Thanks for the answer